# malloc of an array within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have the following code declaring a struct:

```
typedef struct variable_array{
    int length;
    BUCKET * array;
}VARIABLE_ARRAY;

typedef struct bucket{
    int Hash;
    int KeyValue;
    char Data[MAX_INPUT];
    char Key[MAX_INPUT];
}BUCKET;
```

I am then declaring the array with the following code:

```
VARIABLE_ARRAY varArray[Width];
```

Then to create the array withing the VARIABLE_ARRAY i am using this:

```
varArray[hash].array = malloc(varArray[hash].length  * sizeof(BUCKET));
```

However, the `malloc` for some reason never creates more than one element in the array. Even when the length is changed. I am not sure on what steps to take to fix this issue.

Comment: `However, the malloc for some reason never creates more than one element in the array.` How do you know?

Comment: using the debugging tool built in to CLion.

Comment: There is probably a bug somewhere in the code you don't show here. You need to debug this. First look if  `varArray[hash].length` is what you think it is.

Comment: "using the debugging tool built in to CLion" what is that actually telling you? are you certain that it will show a dynamically allocated array differently to a single value?

Comment: What you say is not plausable. `malloc` will just do as told, or return null upon failure. Your debugging tool will just show a pointer, but not how many elements there were allocated in the memory pointed to.

Comment: @Sean - How exactly are you gleaning it from the debugging tools? `malloc` would return the address of the first item. It would look the same for one or many items. But the amount of memory is vastly different.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it is indeed set to 2 which is as expected

Comment: @Sean then the first part of my comment applies here. What makes you think that _malloc for some reason never creates more than one element in the array_?

Comment: Whats `hash` here? And, `Width`? There has to be something wrong about either them.

Comment: Clarify to me - what is being allocated? `VARIABLE_ARRAY`contains `Width` elements (assuming `Width` is valid and greater than 1)? `varArray[hash].array` is correctly allocated (same assumptions for `hash`)? Are you trying to allocate all `array` fields in `varArray` or only the `hash` one?

Comment: You might want to change the `VARIABLE_ARRAY` to use a _flexible array member_ instead.

Comment: @Sean, although we appreciate your efforts to avoid dumping excessive code on us, you have not given us enough to go on.  Our ordinary standard for questions such as this is that a [mcve] be provided.  Presenting one would have forestalled some (but not all) of the questions you have received, and editing the question now to include one will clear some of them up.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with what you are passing to `malloc`, and that something can not be pointed out and/or fixed, unless you don't show us the full code.

`malloc` won't do anything funny unless you do something funny with it.
Its time to look at values you are setting:
`Width`, `hash`, and `varArray[hash].length`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define WIDTH       5
#define MAX_INPUT   32

typedef struct bucket {
    int Hash;
    int KeyValue;
    char Data[MAX_INPUT];
    char Key[MAX_INPUT];
} BUCKET;

typedef struct variable_array {
    int length;
    BUCKET * array;
} VARIABLE_ARRAY;

VARIABLE_ARRAY varArray[WIDTH];

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 0, hash = 5;
    
    for(i = 0; i < hash ; i++)
    {
        varArray[i].array = malloc(sizeof(BUCKET));
        if(varArray[i].array == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nWhoa! Out of memory, returning!");
            return -1;
        }
        varArray[i].array->Hash = i + 10;
        varArray[i].array->KeyValue = i + 15;
        sprintf(varArray[i].array->Data, "Data Instance: %1d", i);
        sprintf(varArray[i].array->Key, "Key Instance: %1d", i);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < hash ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nHash = %d, KeyValue = %d, %s, %s", varArray[i].array->Hash, varArray[i].array->KeyValue, varArray[i].array->Data, varArray[i].array->Key);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < hash ; i++)
    {
        free(varArray[i].array);
        varArray[i].array = NULL;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output it produces is:

```
Hash = 10, KeyValue = 15, Data Instance: 0, Key Instance: 0
Hash = 11, KeyValue = 16, Data Instance: 1, Key Instance: 1
Hash = 12, KeyValue = 17, Data Instance: 2, Key Instance: 2
Hash = 13, KeyValue = 18, Data Instance: 3, Key Instance: 3
Hash = 14, KeyValue = 19, Data Instance: 4, Key Instance: 4
```

which seems as expected.

As you can see, `varArray[hash].length` is what I didn't use at all, So, either I don't understand your design, or its not needed. I'll let you decide that.

**Probable cause of trouble:**

You insisted that the `varArray[hash].length` was set to `2`, so the `malloc` should have allocated a chunk from heap which is of the size equal to twice of `sizeof(BUCKET)`.
Its just that you have one pointer to access two consecutive (logical!) blocks of similar data types.

So, if I add to my code to what it looks like below (Which is very ugly and something which should be avoided for the sake of readability, BTW)

```
printf("\n_______");
printf("\nTake 2!\n");

varArray[0].length = 2;
varArray[0].array = malloc(varArray[0].length * sizeof(BUCKET));
if(varArray[0].array == NULL)
{
    printf("\nWhoa! Out of memory, returning!");
    return -1;
}
varArray[0].array->Hash = 10;
varArray[0].array->KeyValue = 15;
sprintf(varArray[0].array->Data, "Data Instance: %1d", 0);
sprintf(varArray[0].array->Key, "Key Instance: %1d", 0);

printf("\nHash = %d, KeyValue = %d, %s, %s", varArray[0].array->Hash, varArray[0].array->KeyValue, varArray[0].array->Data, varArray[0].array->Key);

(varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Hash))->Hash = 11;
(varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->KeyValue))->KeyValue = 16;
sprintf((varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Data))->Data, "Data Instance: %1d", 1);
sprintf((varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Key))->Key, "Key Instance: %1d", 1);

printf("\nHash = %d, KeyValue = %d, %s, %s", (varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Hash))->Hash, (varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->KeyValue))->KeyValue, (varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Data))->Data, (varArray[0].array+sizeof(BUCKET)+sizeof(varArray[0].array->Key))->Key);

free(varArray[0].array);
varArray[0].array = NULL;
```

It generates an output:

```
Hash = 10, KeyValue = 15, Data Instance: 0, Key Instance: 0
Hash = 11, KeyValue = 16, Data Instance: 1, Key Instance: 1
Hash = 12, KeyValue = 17, Data Instance: 2, Key Instance: 2
Hash = 13, KeyValue = 18, Data Instance: 3, Key Instance: 3
Hash = 14, KeyValue = 19, Data Instance: 4, Key Instance: 4
_______
Take 2!

Hash = 10, KeyValue = 15, Data Instance: 0, Key Instance: 0
Hash = 11, KeyValue = 16, Data Instance: 1, Key Instance: 1
```

which is again, exactly as per expectation.

What obviously won't work here is:

```
// For this code, accessing it like below, will result in a Segmentation Fault!!!
varArray[1].array->Hash = 11;
```

Because, in the snippet above I have not initialized `varArray[1].array` to point to an instance of address of a variable which is of the type `BUCKET`.
So, if at all by an unintended error/bug you have passed `varArray[hash].length * sizeof(BUCKET)` to `malloc`, be certain that you have that much memory allocated if the `malloc` didn't return `NULL`.

And I think that is the exact reason that you are getting a Segmentation Fault when you try to access the next index, by incrementing `hash` somewhere.

Your statement:

> However, the malloc for some reason never creates more than one element in the array. Even when the length is changed.

My guess is, By Segmentation Fault you are assuming that memory is NOT allocated, while it is being allocated. Its just that you are not accessing it the right way.

Comment: You never set `length` in your example, even though you warn that it's important to.

Comment: But then you should show code that doesn't work. In this case, your malloc implies length=1, but the OP complains that malloc seems to think length=1 even though he has verified that length=2. That is a completely different situation.

Comment: @MrLister: Can't do any better than this, at least tonight :)